# I get an SQL syntax error but my query still update's, how to fix that?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I get an error but my query still update's.
here is the error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1' at line 1
```

here is my code:

```
if (isset($_GET['edit'])) {

   $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['edit']);
   $rowchauffeur = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM taxi_drivers WHERE id='$id'") or die(mysqli_error($conn));
   $row = mysqli_fetch_array($rowchauffeur);

}

if (isset($_POST['newdriverprofile'])) {

  $newdrivername = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['newdrivername']);
  $newdriverfamilyname = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['newdriverfamilyname']);
  $newdrivercarnumber = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['newdrivercarnumber']);
  $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['id']);

  $themodifier = mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE taxi_drivers SET prenom='$newdrivername', nomdefamille='$newdriverfamilyname', numerodevoiture='$newdrivercarnumber' WHERE id='$id'");
  $rowchauffeur = mysqli_query($conn, $themodifier) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
  echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=index.php'>";
}


echo '

    <form method="POST" action="edit.php" >
    <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
    <label>Prénom:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="newdrivername" value="'.mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $row[1]).'" required>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
  <div class="form-group col-md-3">
    <label>Nom de famille:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="newdriverfamilyname" value="'.mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $row[2]).'"  required>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
  <div class="form-group col-md-3">
    <label>Numéro de voiture:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="newdrivercarnumber" value="'.mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $row[3]).'" required>
  </div>
  </div>
  <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="id" value="'.mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $row[id]).'">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="newdriverprofile">Modifier</button>
</form>

';
```

How to remove that error, I'm having a hard time finding what is wrong.

Most of you will say the whole code is wrong, but give me a chance i'm a complete newby.

Comment: Use prepared and bound queries.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the error by removing :

```
$rowchauffeur = mysqli_query($conn, $themodifier) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
```